# How to write nested python dicts to separate columns and rows with tabs and newlines in csv or excel file?

Tags: python, excel, csv

I have some nested dictionaries of the form:
`nestedDicts = {"vertical1st":{"channel1st":{"format1st":{"size":1},"format2nd":{"size":2}}},"vertical2nd":{"channel2nd":{"format3rd":{"size":3},"format4th":{"size":4}}}}`

and I'd like to write it out in the form of:

[image]

to a csv or excel file.

I've tried using the `csv.DictWriter` and standard .write schemes with "\t" and "\n"  as well as trying it in pandas but in the ultimate csv file it outputs everything in a single column or multiple rows in the same column.

Any advice on how to do this formating would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never been working with this but I've just written simply solution for .csv files. I hope it'll help you!

Solution:

```py
import csv

nestedDicts = {"format1nd":{"channel1st":{"format1st":{"size":1},"format2nd":{"size":2}}},"vertical2nd":{"channel2nd":{"format3rd":{"size":3},"format4th":{"size":4}}}}

def specific_writer(d, iterator=0):
    for i in d:
        if isinstance(d[i], dict):
            writer.writerow([" " for j in range(iterator)] + [i])
            specific_writer(d[i], iterator+1)
        else:
            writer.writerow([" " for j in range(iterator)] + [i + str(d[i])])
            iterator = 0

with open("fruits.csv", "w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='|')
    specific_writer(nestedDicts)

f.close()
```

Received file:

```
format1nd
 |channel1st
 | |format1st
 | | |size1
 | |format2nd
 | | |size2
vertical2nd
 |channel2nd
 | |format4th
 | | |size4
 | |format3rd
 | | |size3
```

Comment: Probably, you can use this function with excel files. Good luck!

Comment: Is there away to transform  the | delimiter to actually move the text into separate columns though? For the purposes Im using I really need them in separate columns not just labeled by a particular number of delimiters.

Comment: Actually this does work if i replace the delimiter with \t and force open as .xls.

Comment: @Wilhelm If I've helped you, please accept and rate the answer. Thanks!